# How do I use a refresh token to get a new access token for Google SpreadsheetsService

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to build an application which reads and writes to a private Google Spreadsheet. For this I need to use Google OAuth2.0 .

My problem is that I lose access after 1 hour. I assume this means that the refresh token is not being used correctly. Here is my code for handling authentication:

```
public static SpreadsheetsService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
    {

        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  // view and manage your files and documents
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,  
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,   
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,   
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,   
                                         DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,   
                                         "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
                                         "https://docs.google.com/feeds"

        };  


        try
        {
            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , userName
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore("MY.APP.Auth.Store")).Result;

            SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService(My App");
            var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("My App");

            requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", credential.Token.AccessToken));
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + ": An authentication error occurred: " + ex.InnerException);
            return null;

        }

    }
```

How do I go about making the refresh token being used correctly?

Comment: Its because you are mixing two different api systems.   If its your own spreadsheet and you personally control I have an example with a service account that might help  http://www.daimto.com/google-sheets-with-c/   I haven't gotten around to getting it working with Oauth2 yet.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo, unfortunately I need to get it working with OAuth2. Thanks for your tutorials, btw, they have really been an enormous help :-)

Comment: Ok then here is a hack:  you are also using drive.  If you create a driveservice and send a dummy request against it.   It will fetch you a new access token automatically if its needed then you can add it to your sheet request.

Comment: Awesome, let me try that...

Comment: seriously a hack there should be a method we can call to refresh the token on request but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: If only there was a way to get a SpreadSheetsService from a DriveService... :-(

Comment: the spreadsheet API  is an old Gdata API,  drive is a discovery API,  Gdata APIs are the old APIs discovery APIs are the nice shinny new APIs.   So you are trying to get your grandfather and your baby sister talking about phone systems.    They can talk but its really not easy to get them to understand eachother

Comment: @DaImTo, thank you so much! It seems to be working! Would you like to post the answer, or shall I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the current Google .NET client library to authenticate. 
When you create a service, it normally will automatically refresh your access token when needed.  However, you are sending an access token to an old Gdata library, which doesn't automatically refresh it.

If you create a drive service and run a dummy request against it once an hour it will refresh your access token for you when needed.

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                                                            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",});

// Dummy request example:
FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
list.MaxResults = 1;
list.Q = "title=dummysearch";
FileList dummyFeed = list.Execute();
// End of Dummy request
```